# "conversion to const char*" error when passing string to function

Tags: c++, string, parameters, char, constants

I tried to pass a string value to a function, but the DevC++5.6.1 reports an error (invalid conversion from char to const char*). Here is the program:

```c++
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string mysubstr(string target, int start_pos, string end_char) {
    for(int i = 0; i < target.size(); ++i)
        if(target[i] == ".") 
            return target.substr(0, i);
    return target;
}

int main() {
    string temp;
    cin >> temp; 
    string day0 = mysubstr(temp, 0, '.');
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder why this happens and how to fix it. Thank you.
By the way: There is the same erro if the function head (5th line) is changed to

```c++
string mysubstr(const string &target, int start_pos, string end_char) {
```

Edit: The function should be the following. Two modifications to the original one: (1) The caller should use double quote; (2) in comparison I should use target.substr(i, 0). (3) The two parameters start_pos and end_char are used now.

```c++
string mysubstr(string target, int start_pos, string end_char) {
    for(int i = 0; i < target.size(); ++i)
        if(target.substr(i, 1) == end_char) 
            return target.substr(0, i);
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a character with a string (`target[i] == "."`) and passing a character to a string parameter (`'.'` for `end_char`).  Note that you don't actually *use* `end_char` in your function, nor `start_pos` for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a character `'.'` to a parameter of type `const char*`. The types don't match which is your problem. You probably want to use a string literal:

```
string day0 = mysubstr(temp, 0, ".");
//                              ^ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter to your function is a `string`, but when you call it, you are passing it a `char` instead.  You can solve the problem by putting that argument in double-quotes instead of single quotes, because `char` arrays are implicitly converted to strings.